# Fill <UL> indent with line

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to fill the `<UL>` indent with a line (or dots or whatever)?

Html

```
<ul>Foo
   <ul>Bar
      <ul>Foo
      </ul>
   </ul>
</ul>
```

Result

```
Foo 
-----Bar 
----------Foo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a not so generic solution, but a quick win:

**HTML:**

```
<ul>Foo
   <ul>Bar
      <ul>Foo
      </ul>
   </ul>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul > ul:before {
    content: "------";
}

ul > ul > ul:before {
    content: "------------";
}
```

See for yourself in this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cz4HG/)!